# if then else condition in json schema

Tags: javascript, python, json.net

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
"$id": "http://example.com/example.json",
"type": "object",
"required": [
    "FileID",
    "MString",
    "desc",
    "elements"
],
"properties": {
    "FileID": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "MString": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "desc": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "elements": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
                "Mytype",
                "filename",
                "compression"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "Mytype": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "filename": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "compression": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I want to add a condition in this schema (if Mytype == "abc") then "filename" can be only "tutor.txt". Please can some one help me out to write this add this condition in the schema. I tried many ways but always giving some error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches to achieve that behavior. One is using conditional in-place applicators, which are available since JSON Schema Draft 7. The syntax looks as follows (I will extract the involved subschema for the sake of clarity):

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "Mytype",
    "filename",
    "compression"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "Mytype": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "filename": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "compression": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "if": {
    "properties": {"Mytype": {"const": "abc"}}
  },
  "then": {
    "properties": {"filename": {"const": "tutor.txt"}}
  }
}
```

The following JSON document is valid against this JSON Schema:

```
{
  "Mytype": "abc",
  "filename": "tutor.txt",
  "compression": "foo"
}
```

And this will be **invalid**:

```
{
  "Mytype": "abc",
  "filename": "tutor",
  "compression": "foo"
}
```

For more complex conditions, JSON Schema provides an `"else"` keyword. To learn more I suggest you to check out [this educative reference](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/index.html), under the *Applying subschemas conditionally* section.

On top of this conditional approach, you can express this same grammar by using boolean-logic applicators instead of the conditional applicators demonstrated above. Personally, Though usually more verbose, I tend to prefer this solution as it represents a purely declarative solution instead of that "procedural" `if-then-else` notion, remaining more clear after all.

Here is the example:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "Mytype",
    "filename",
    "compression"
  ],
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "Mytype": {
          "const": "abc"
        },
        "filename": {
          "const": "tutor.txt"
        },
        "compression": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "Mytype": {
          "not": {
            "const": "abc"
          }
        },
        "filename": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "compression": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Explanation: the JSON document has to be valid against **only** one of the subschemas included in the `"oneOf"`. The first expresses the constrained case obliging `"filename"` to be `"tutor.txt"` if `"Mytype"` is `"abc"`. The second subschema represents the case when `"Mytype"` is **not** `"abc"`, so the `"filename"` is not constrained, just any `"string"`.

As stated, the boolean-logic applicators syntax yields more verbose schemas, and they may need some time to get used to them, but overall they are the best option in my opinion.